# Legend showing wrong color in ggplot geom_sf

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-sf

I am making a map where I need some cities to be points of a certain color (A cities) and some cities to be points of a different color (B cities). All B cities are also on the A list so I put the B geom_sf second so that those points would layer on top of the A cities.

On the map itself this worked, the orange dots are visible on top of the others. But in the legend both A and B are orange. I need A to be the dark color!

(Please ignore other aesthetic issues with the map haha, I'll get there)

sample map showing issue:

[image: sample map showing issue]

```
usa_states <- map_data("state") %>%
  rename(lon=long, State=region, County=subregion)

Acities <- read_csv("Acities.csv")
Acities_sf <- st_as_sf(Acities, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

Bcities <- read_csv("Bcities.csv")
Bcities_sf <- st_as_sf(Bcities, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs=4326)

AandBmap <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=usa_states, aes(x=lon, y=lat, group=group), fill="#DAD9D5", color="white") + #this is a gray US background
  coord_quickmap() + 
  geom_sf(data=Acities_sf, color = "#174337", size = 1.5, aes(fill="A Location")) + #A cities
  geom_sf(data=Bcities_sf, color = "#EAAA1B", size = 1.5, aes(fill="A and B Location")) + #B cities
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL)) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) + 
  theme_void()
AandBmap
```

Apologies, I can't figure out how/where to upload my sample data, if someone can point that to me I can do that. In the meantime this should work instead of loading the csvs.

```
Acities <- matrix(c(34.0549, -118.243, 38.9072, -77.0369, 29.9511, -90.0715, 40.8137, -96.7026, 40.7128, -74.006), nrow=5, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)

Acities <- matrix(c(34.0549, -118.243, 40.7128, -74.006), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have set your colors as parameters outside of `aes()` and then map your desired labels on the `fill` aes inside `aes()`. Instead you have to map on the `color` aes and set your desired colors and labels using `scale_color_manual`. Additionally you could simplify by binding your city data into one dataframe and by adding an identifier column for the city:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.3, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(maps)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

Acities <- as.data.frame(Acities)
Bcities <- as.data.frame(Bcities)
names(Acities) <- names(Bcities) <- c("lon", "lat")

usa_states <- map_data("state") %>%
  rename(lon = long, State = region, County = subregion)

AB_cities <- list(A = Acities, B = Bcities) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "city")

AB_cities_sf <- AB_cities |>
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(
    data = usa_states, aes(x = lon, y = lat, group = group),
    fill = "#DAD9D5", color = "white"
  ) +
  geom_sf(data = AB_cities_sf, size = 1.5, aes(color = city)) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(A = "#174337", B = "#EAAA1B"),
    labels = c(A = "A Location", B = "A and B Location")
  ) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your sample data is not quite correct. I corrected it in my solution. Stefan gave you the right reasons, why your plot doesn't work as expected. A slightly easier solution might be to create a label in your data and use anti_join to filter the data that has both. Also please note, that if you want to use the fill aesthetic you need a shape that supports it. Here is a working solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

usa_states <- map_data("state") |> 
  rename(lon=long, State=region, County=subregion)

Acities <- matrix(c(34.0549, -118.243, 38.9072, -77.0369, 29.9511, -90.0715, 40.8137, -96.7026, 40.7128, -74.006), nrow=5, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  rename(lat = 1, lon = 2) |> 
  mutate(Location = "A Location")

Bcities <- matrix(c(34.0549, -118.243, 40.7128, -74.006), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) |> 
 as_tibble() |> 
 rename(lat = 1, lon = 2) |> 
 mutate(Location = "A & B Location")

Acities <- Acities |> 
  anti_join(Bcities, by = c("lat", "lon"))

cities <- bind_rows(
 Acities,
 Bcities
)


cities_sf <- st_as_sf(cities, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs=4326)

AandBmap <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=usa_states, aes(x=lon, y=lat, group=group), fill="#DAD9D5", color="white") + #this is a gray US background
  geom_sf(data=cities_sf, color = "#174337", shape = 21, size = 1.5, aes(fill=Location)) + # All cities
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL)) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) + 
  theme_void()

AandBmap
```

[image]